# Passing data from a cell to a label on a DetailViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, tableview, uistoryboardsegue

I need a little hint on passing data from a cell to a label on a detailViewController.

Using X-Code 4.6.2, Objective-C with Storyboard.

I've got a TableView with all my names init. If I click on a cell it goes to the DetailView.

I've set up an segue to the DetailView. But how do I get the information from the selected cell to the Detail View? For Example I click on row 1 and it is supposed to display the name Albert Anker in a label.

In my viewController.m

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"toDetail"]) {


    NSString *Name = @"PhoneBooth";
    DetailViewController *DVC = [segue destinationViewController];
    DVC.nameString = Name;

}
```

In my DetailViewController.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[label setText:welcomeString];
}
```

I've watched several Videos on this subject but none of theme work.
The Code above comes from a Tutorial that uses three Buttons and three different named segues. I was hoping I could use that for my cell. I guess I need to use "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" but how?

- I did import the DetailViewController header to ViewController.m
- Segue goes from prototypeCell to DetailView.
- DataSource and Delegate are connected to the tableView.
- ViewController is embeded in NavigationController.

I hope I was able to describe my problem correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I`ve figuered it out.

I forgot to @synthsize my label and the NSString.

THX anyway.